# A lonely Riley Riddle

Tags: riddle, wordplay

> My prefix adds a lot of grain
>
> My infix emits a powerful shine
>
> If you'd come destroy my base
>
> I wouldn't be on time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finishing what MacGyver88 started, you are

> **ISOLATE**

My prefix adds a lot of grain

> **ISO** - the larger an images' ISO rating is, the grainier it is

My infix emits a powerful shine

> **SOL** - the sun, just as MacGyver88 suggested

If you'd come destroy my base

I wouldn't be on time

> **LATE** - not on time, again as MacGyver88 suggested

Title

> **ISOLATE** - "an individual socially withdrawn or removed from society", according to [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/isolate)

Answer (score 4):

You could be

> **DESOLATE**

My prefix adds a lot of grain

> **DES** - maybe an acronym for something dealing with grains (food, grainy picture, small things ???)

My infix emits a powerful shine

> **SOL** - the sun

If you'd come destroy my base

> BY REMOVING THE FIRST TWO PARTS, or desolate - synonym of destroy

I wouldn't be on time

> **LATE** - not on time

Title

> **DESOLATE** - could refer to a lonely, out of the way place.

Comment: You're so nearly there, you picked up more hints than I meant though ;). Only the prefix isn't as I meant.

Comment: @SoftwAir, It was a toss-up between the two. I went with my gut. I read a little too deep into it. No worries. :)